# Jumping description next to +/- icon jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery Accordion where I use a "+" and "-" icon. 
Next to those icons you can see a description (in this case "Part1" and "Part2")

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        animate: 500
    }).on("click", "div", function (e) {
        $("div.ui-accordion-header").each(function (i, el) {
            if ($(this).is(".ui-state-active")) {
                $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("-")
            } else {
                $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("+")
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="js_button">
        <span class="panel-icon">+</span>Part1</div> 
    <div class="panel">
                <p>Content1</p>
                </div>

</div>
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Part2</div> 
    <div class="panel">
                <p>Content2</p>
                </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.accordion {
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.0;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
     margin-top: 1%;
}
.js_button {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline-width: 0;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.js_button:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
}
.panel {
    width: 99%;
    height: 20%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When I click on the button and the "+" icon changes to the "-" icon the description (Part1, Part2) next to the icon somehow "jumps" to the left since the "-" icon seems to be smaller than the "+" icon. 
How can I avoid this and make the description next to the icon stay at the same position and not moving at all?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Here is also a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypv8yow1/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply give the span a fixed width. To make it work you have to float it first.

```
span.panel-icon {
    float:left;
    width: 10px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypv8yow1/14/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :-)